# How to use the $compile service to include HTML data with AngularJS directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have a controller which is populating content to content areas using ng-repeat. The issue is that some of this content needs to come front template files and so needs to be compiled 'on the fly'. Right now I have this function dynamically adding content:

```
$scope.layouts = [

    { id: 'Dashboard', icon: 'dashboard', view: '/qph/views/Dashboard.php' },
    { id: 'Customers', icon: 'people', view: '/qph/views/users.php' },
    { id: 'Quotes', icon: 'format_list_bulleted', view: '/qph/views/Quotes.php' }

];

$scope.workspace = {};    

var getTemplate = function(id){

    var view = 'test.php';

    $timeout(function() { //added timeout

    if($templateCache.get(view) === undefined) {
            $templateRequest(view).then(function (data) {
                $scope.workspaces.forEach(function (v) {
                    if (v.id == id) v.content = $compile(data)($scope);
                });
            });

    } else {
        $scope.workspaces.forEach(function (v) {
            if (v.id == id) v.content = $compile($templateCache.get(view))($scope);
        });

    }
    }, 2000);
};

$scope.workspaces =
    [
        { id: 1, name: "Dashboard", icon: 'dashboard', active:true  }
    ];
getTemplate(1);
```

I have checked that the data variable has the html content as expected, but the compile is outputting the following:

```
{"0":{"jQuery331075208394539601512":{"$scope":"$SCOPE","$ngControllerController":{}}},"length":1}
```

Does anyone know why its not compiling the html content as expected?

Here is the template content for reference:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" ng-controller="UserController">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="well">
        <h3>Users</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 10px" ng-click="user.getUsers()">Get Users!</button>
        <ul class="list-group" ng-if="user.users">
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in user.users">
                <h4>{{user.name}}</h4>
                <h5>{{user.email}}</h5>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="user.error">
            <strong>There was an error: </strong> {{user.error.error}}
            <br>Please go back and login again
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the tabs view that is to display the compiled content:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs workspace-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item" ng-repeat="space in workspaces">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#workspace{{space.id}}" ng-class="(space.active == true ) ? 'active show': ''">
            <span class="hidden-sm-up"><i class="material-icons md-24">{{space.icon}}</i></span>
            <span class="hidden-xs-down">{{space.name}}</span>
            <button ng-click="workspace.remove($index)">x</button>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content workspace-content">
    <div ng-repeat="space in workspaces" id="workspace{{space.id}}" class="tab-pane fade in" ng-class="(space.active == true ) ? 'active show': ''">
        {{space.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PatricioVargas This is AngularJS (I said in the title)

Comment: @PatricioVargas Everything coded here is reference from AngularJS resources. If there is something here that has a better alternative I'm all ears.

Comment: @PatricioVargas I've just read my post and I've not mentioned component once. I appreciate your looking at this, but I think this might not be something you can assist with, but thanks anyway.

Comment: How are you attaching the compiled output to the DOM?

Comment: @PatricioVargas The view content uses code that is available in Angular and AngularJS and is demonstrated in my above. Please leave it now as there is sufficient information and you seem confused. Thank you

Comment: @georgeawg An array in the scope is appended and is handled in a ng-repeat loop. I will add this part to the content above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) service creates a [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) object that needs to be added to the DOM with a [jqLite or jQuery append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method. Using interpolation `{{ }}` will only render the stringified value of the `jqLite` object.

```
<div class="tab-content workspace-content">
    <div ng-repeat="space in workspaces" id="workspace{{space.id}}" class="tab-pane fade in" ng-class="(space.active == true ) ? 'active show': ''">
        ̶{̶{̶s̶p̶a̶c̶e̶.̶c̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶}̶}̶
        <compile html="space.html"></compile>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead, use a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to compile and append the HTML data to the DOM:

```
app.directive("compile", function($compile) {
    return {
        link: postLink,
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var rawHTML = scope.$eval(attrs.html)
        var linkFn = $compile(rawHTML);
        var $html = linkFn(scope);
        elem.append($html);
    }
})
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - HTML Compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler).

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. I tested this and it works, but only if the process happens quickly, ie the template doesn't take too long to load. It fails to render at all otherwise. I've added a timeout in the code above to simulate this.

Comment: If the other answer works for you, why not just use the [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive?

Comment: That works! I'm new to Angular and did not know the ng-include directive would handle that, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a directive.

```
app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'test.php',
    controller: 'UserController'
  };
})
```

Template cache will be managed automatically.

Comment: Tried this one and it worked, however its static and so unable to receive a template name and return it. I'm testing to making it dynamic, but no luck yet.